# Linear dual of vector fields

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, modules

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold and $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is the set
of smooth vector fields on $M$. There are basically two different linear
structures on $\mathfrak{X}(M)$:

1.) $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a (infinite dimensional) $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

2.) $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is an $C^\infty(M)$-module, where $C^\infty(M)$ means the algebra of smooth real valued functions on $M$.

(These structures are related by a so called Lie-Rinehart pair, but that's irrelevant for the question)

Now, the $C^\infty(M)$-dual of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is well known and precisely 
the $C^\infty(M)$-module of *differential one-forms*, that is

$$\Omega^1(M)=Hom_{C^\infty}(\mathfrak{X}(M),C^\infty(M))$$

The question is:

Is there moreover a common description of the $\mathbb{R}$-dual of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$? I
mean, how can we think about the elements of

$$
Hom_\mathbb{R}(\mathfrak{X}(M),\mathbb{R})
$$

and are there places in mathematics where they appear?

I know this is pretty vague, but I'm just trying to 'get a hand' on this kind of
dual.

Edit: From some of the comments/answers, it became clear to me, that there are better understood restrictions of $Hom_\mathbb{R}(\mathfrak{X}(M),\mathbb{R})$,
so the question is generalized to

Is there a common description of (some meaningful vector subspace of)  the $\mathbb{R}$-dual of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$?

Comment: All I can think of is integration; take some function $f$ with compact support, let $g(X) = \int_M Xf dV.$ I guess you need a volume form as well.

Comment: A related question, why do we not look at the full dual to infinite dimensional vector spaces in the usual functional analysis course? As I recall, the set of linear functionals is bigger than the set of bounded linear functionals... but, I second @WillJagy's comment.

Comment: With $M=\mathbb{R}$  (probably for any $M$), the continuous dual of $C^\infty(M)$ is the compactly supported distributions, so the linear dual includes this at least.  But I don't think this is a very useful observation.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Without a topology it's not analysis anymore

Comment: The dual is a certain completion of the space of smooth 1-chains in M, however the isomorphism is noncanonical as you need a Riemannian metric to convert vector fields to forms. The you use Whitney's theorem from his Geometric Integration Theory.

Comment: @mathematician: Can you explain or reference your first comment a little more?

Comment: @studiosus: As you claim to know the answer,please explain that in detail. If with 1-chains, you mean one forms, with exterior differential or something, I really can't see, why they come into play.

Comment: The question is almost a duplicate of the one I already answered, I just have to sift through my answer to find it.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook My way of looking at it. The linear dual is so much bigger than the topological dual that neither is there usually any useful characterisation (in the sense that taking any Hamel basis $\{x_i:i\in I\}$, $I$ an arbitrary index set, one can define linear functionals taking any kind of values imaginable) nor can such a large essentially unrestricted collection of functionals be forced to provide information about the original space.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Probably every kind of pathology, subject only to linearity, can be exhibited.

Comment: @mathematician surely some analysis can be done across multiple topologies at once, in fact, this might make an interesting question. Perhaps I'll ask it later today.

Comment: @InTransit indeed, this is why I made the comment, I saw the question refer to "$\mathbb{R}$-dual without qualification, as we see in studiosus' answer and the surrounding materials, the dual used is not the $\mathbb{R}$-dual, but rather some suitably restricted subset which is not hopelessly infinite in the manner you indicate.

Comment: Although it was not the original question, I'm ok, with meaningful restrictions of the true $\mathbb{R}$-dual. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, by introducing a Riemannian metric, we get an isomorphism between the spaces of vector fields and (smooth) 1-forms on $M$. Thus, I will now work with 1-forms. In order to get a meaningful answer, I will restrict to the  *continuous dual* of $\Omega^1(M)$, where continuity is defined as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_(mathematics)). Then the dual space to $\Omega^1(M)$ is the space $D_1(M)$ of *1-currents* on $M$. Examples of 1-currents are given by *1-chains*, which are formal (real) linear combinations of smooth maps $\sigma: [0,1]\to M$ and duality is given by integration:
$$
<\omega, \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \sigma_i > = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \int_{\sigma_i} \omega. 
$$
Let me call such currents "polyhedral".  Theory of currents is well-developed and you can find its most detailed treatment in the monumental book "Geometric Measure Theory" by H.Federer. In particular, under certain extra restrictions (rectifiability and integral multiplicity), Federer proves that every current can be approximated (in suitable topology) by polyhedral ones.

Federer's book is long and written in a very formal style where all the geometric intuition is left out. A much more gentle, geometric (and much less detailed) treatment can be found in F.Morgan's book "Geometric Measure Theory: A Beginner's Guide".

Lastly, for the dual question to yours (what is the "dual" to the space of polyhedral 1-currents) and my answer to it, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658214/when-can-a-functional-be-written-as-the-integral-of-a-1-form/659015#659015).

Comment: That's sounds good. However before I can mark it as the answer, I need to reed through your references, since I didn't here much about this stuff before.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus: Of course. Start with wikipedia page; then browse Morgan's book.